# Ошибка в консоле 'classList' of undefined

Tags: javascript

при клике ошибка Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
at HTMLLIElement.y

```
let nth = document.querySelectorAll(".nth")

for(i=0;i<n.length;i++){
    n[i].onclick = y;
    function y(){
        nth[i].classList.toggle("nth-n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Беда была с названием переменной. Сначала `name`, потом `n`, потом `nth`

```js
let nth = document.querySelectorAll(".nth");

for(let i=0;i<nth.length;i++){
  nth[i].onclick = function(){
      nth[i].classList.toggle("nth-n");
  }
}
```

```css
body{
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
.nth{
  height: 100px;
  background: #cda;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nth-n{
  background: #acd;
}
```

```html
<div class="nth"></div>
<div class="nth"></div>
<div class="nth"></div>
<div class="nth"></div>
```